# Is it necessary to initialize static class variables?

Tags: python, class-variables

I started learning python few days ago and I am trying out different things.

I wrote code as follows:

```
class ConsumeState:
    token
```

I got following error for this code

```
NameError: name 'token' is not defined
```

So I initialized `token` to `"abc"` and the error was gone.

My question is what if I don't want to define the static variable at this point what should I do for that? Is it always necessary to initialize static variable in python?

Comment: If you don't want to define a static variable, then don't do it.

Comment: You could do `token = None`

Comment: `token = None` If you don't want to give it any value, but still want to declare it.

Comment: Python doesn't have variable declarations. You *always* assign to a variable. If you don't want to assign to it now, the *don't*, and when you do, just do `ConsumeState.token = 'whatever'`

Answer (score 0):

Unlike C,Java,C# and so on, in python you don't to initialize a variable or even declare that it is a String or int or float.

You can declare like this:

```
u=set()
u.add("stack")
u.add("overflow")
```

You can also do this:

```
u=set(["stack","overflow"])
```

That is a one liner but creates a list first and then creates a set out of it.

This creates a list with the powers of all the numbers from 0-4. You don't need to declare that l is a list and then add stuff in it. You also dont need to declare that x is an int or even initialize it.

```
l = [x for x in range(5)]
```

In python you can also do this:

```
s="stack"
s=[x for x in "overflow"]
```

See there? i just changed the type of s from string to a list. I can also add different objects in the same list.

```
s.append(5)
```

if i were to print s now i would get this:

```
['o', 'v', 'e', 'r', 'f', 'l', 'o', 'w', 5]
```

5 is still an integer inside a list of what was only string objects.

I can also do operations with same integer that i cant with the other objects

```
print(s[-1:][0]/5)
```

this for example prints 5/5. s[-1:] tells python to return a list of just the last object. On that list i pick [0]  , which is 5 and then i divide it with 5.

if i were to do a forloop, i would get error that i can't use divide operation with string types.

If you were to do something like this:

```
u=set()
def pwsdw():
    some code here..
    u.add(x)
```

You would receive error that you didn't initialize the variable.

You can do this however:

```
u=set()
def pwsdw():
    global u
    some code
    u.add(x)
```

All in all, python is an extremely flexible language. Have fun.